# Set Window owner inside of an UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, window, parent, owner

I have an `UserControl` that shows a window without an icon in the Taskbar, the problem is when the main window lost the focus and get it again the window without taskbar icon is behind the main window and is difficult show it in front again, this issue is solved using `window.Owner = this;` when the class is a window, but when is `UserControl` or other type (e.g. `ListBoxItem`, `Viewbox`) I can't do this. I tried to do this `control.Owner = (Window)this;` but the result throws an exception that a `Grid` cannot be converted into a `Window`

Comment: maybe `control.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;`

Comment: Or may be you can find the visual parent window via VisualTreeHelper.

Answer (score 9):

use

```
window.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (int  index=0;index< App.Current.Windows.Count;index++ )
        {
            if (App.Current.Windows[index].Title == "MyWindow")
                control.Owner = App.Current.Windows[index];
        }
```

here Title is the Title of Window which you want to set as owner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is not exactly I'm trying to solve, but I've found it useful in some parts of the application I'm creating, Thanks, I'll give +1.